# Calling Composer With Specific PHP Version on Homestead

Tags: php, composer-php, homestead

I'm using Homestead to develop a site that will be on a server with PHP 7.0. I want to use `.env` files, so I ran this Composer command:

```
composer require vlucas/phpdotenv
```

When I perused the file, `composer.lock`, I noticed that a dependency, `doctrine/annotations`, was requiring PHP 7.1.

I tried adding this to my `composer.json` file:

```
"config": {
    "platform": {
        "php": "~7.0"
    }
},
```

When I run `composer update`, I get this error:

```
[UnexpectedValueException]
Invalid version string "~7.0"
```

I realize that this is because PHP 7.2 is the default version on Homestead. How do I run Composer with PHP 7.0 instead of PHP 7.2?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Run the command `php70` and that will set PHP 7.0 to the default system version of PHP, then you can run `composer` normally.

Comment: `php70: command not found` You're missing that alias from your `aliases` file. Copy the contents of this file: https://github.com/laravel/homestead/blob/master/resources/aliases to your ~/.bash_aliases then logout of vagrant and back in and it should work.

Comment: If you add those additional instructions, I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 20):

Executing `which composer` will give you this output:

```
/usr/local/bin/composer
```

The [Homestead documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/homestead#multiple-php-versions) discusses the [multiple PHP versions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/homestead#multiple-php-versions) supported and how to call them from the command line for Artisan. Combining that with the composer path above allows you to do this:

```
php7.0 /usr/local/bin/composer update
```

Comment: You might also need to install php7.0-mcrypt. https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/homestead-3-and-mcrypt